# What is a Eigen::array (not Eigen::Array)

Tags: c++, eigen, tensor, eigen3

I'm using eigen tensor library and it seems to me that shuffle() method wants as input an object Eigen::array<type,int>.

In my implementation I have a std::list of int I need to pass to shuffle (of course I know the second int param (the rank) only at runtime!)

Comment: I doubt they would break their naming convention and create a type with a lowercase name, most likely they are referring to `Eigen::Array<>`.

Comment: You can see here, in section Reduction Dimensions, an example where they create an object with std::array
https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/eigen_tensors.html

Comment: I agree with you that is strange they defined their own array, but I tested that example on my laptop and it works writing Eigen::array ...

Comment: Sorry, on my previous comment I wrote std::array instead of Eigen::array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not long ago Eigen's Tensor module was C++03 compatible. That implies that `std::array` is not available. For that reason the Tensor module defined its own `Eigen::array` class that is in fact a typedef for `std::array` if C++11 is available.

The file [unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/util/EmulateArray.h](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/master/unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/src/util/EmulateArray.h) contains something that boils down to (pseudo-code)

```
#if C++11 not available
  // Define a custom std::array like Eigen::array class
#else
  template <typename T, std::size_t N> using array = std::array<T, N>;
#endif
```

The Tensor module has dropped C++03 compatibility and parts of this code could probably be removed.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. FYI, I think you have the if condition backwards.